# Problem with smooth shading a simple triangulated mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders, edges

I'm having trouble with a relatively simple mesh – a grid that I triangulated and then shaped by using sculpt and manually moving vertices.

When smooth shading is enabled, I see a lot of artifacts along the edges.
I'm trying to make this appear as a smooth, undulated ground plane. What could be causing this issue?

[image]

[image: Mesh shaded]
[image: Mesh edit mode]

Comment: Hello, it maybe inverted normals? In Edit mode select all and try a Shift N, also try Clear Custom Split Normals Data in the Data panel > Geometry Data, or please share your file

Comment: I've added the file to the original post. Normals do not appear to be flipped and I do not see any custom split normals data to clear. Thx!

Comment: Make sure you don't have "Scene World" turned on, it under viewport shading, lighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things here:

- The sun *Angle* value is very low, it makes the shadow very sharp
- The light angle in the 3D scene is very low which increases the sharp effect
- The material is rather dark (i.e. base color of the *Principled BSDF*) which forces you to sete a very high light *Strength* value and increase the effect, 100 is very high for a *Sun*, it should be around 4
- If it's not enough, give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object to (virtually) increase its resolution

Comment: As suggested, I set the sun angle back to default and tried strength in the range 1 to 4. I set the ground material to the default (white) and changed the direction of the sun. It seems like this last factor is the main contributor to the artifacting – I can get rid of the artifacts by having the sun more above the scene, but I have to say I'm surprised how any kind of side angle sun re-introduces them. Is there a better way to side-light a scene (ie, sunset)?

Comment: You can add a Subdivision Surface modifier if you want the surface to look smoother